# Getting rid of a custom Shell on a LiteOS based outdoor camera

Tags: firmware, hardware, serial-communication

I started reversing [this camera](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4001151246566.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2esp&spm=a2g0o.9042311.0.0.5d8563c0ttw3sd) in order to get rid of the unwanted traffic it constantly does towards Chinese servers.
I have a serial access to it thanks to an obvious UART port (bottom left in the picture).
[image: camera board]
The camera is based on a *Hi3518* chip and runs `Huawei LiteOS 1.4.5`:

```
SPI Nor(cs 0) ID: 0xef 0x60 0x17
Block:64KB Chip:8MB Name:"W25Q64FW"
SPI Nor total size: 8MB


********hello Huawei LiteOS ARM926********

version : Huawei LiteOS V200R001C10B017
open-version : Huawei LiteOS 1.4.5
build data : May  2 2018 19:06:05

**********************************
********Hello Huawei LiteOS********

version : Huawei LiteOS V200R001C10B017
open-version : Huawei LiteOS 1.4.5
build data : May  2 2018 19:06:05

********
Huawei LiteOS # Spi Nor ID:0xEF 0x60 0x17 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Spi Nor Flash Info:
Name:"W25Q64FW" Size:8MB Block:64KB
osal_proc_mkdir - parent is NULL! proc=0x80976bd0
<6>Hisilicon Media Memory Zone Manager
```

And once started it does not give a typical `/bin/sh` to the console, but instead a custom made *CLI* they call a *shell*.
Here are the commands that this "shell" has:

```
Huawei LiteOS # help                                                            
*******************shell commands:*************************                     
                                                                                
ap_test       armbenv       arp           call          cat           cat_logmpp
    cd            cp                                                            
cpup          debug         dns           excInfo       findsym       format    
    free          help                                                          
hiddrs        himd          himm          hwi           i2c_read      i2c_write 
    ifconfig      lddrop                                                        
local_alarm   ls            mclose        memcheck      mkdir         mopen     
    mount         msgqueue                                                      
nand_bad      netstat       ntpdate       partinfo      partition     ping      
    pwd           readreg                                                       
reset         rm            rmdir         sem           sendbps       shutdown  
    sleep_device  ssp_read                                                      
ssp_write     sta_test      statfs        swtmr         sync          systeminfo
    task          telnet                                                        
tftp          touch         uart_close    uart_config   uart_read     uart_write
    umount        uname                                                         
writeproc     writereg
```

Note those commands are functions from this custom *CLI*, **not** actual *UNIX/Linux/busybox* commands.

Those are documented, as is the whole *LiteOS* SDK, in a pretty well put documentation available on their [Github](https://github.com/LiteOS/LiteOS), but nothing really give access to the underlying Linux system, unlike many *Hi35xx* based devices, looks like their build is configured with this [shell enabled](https://github.com/LiteOS/LiteOS/blob/master/.config#L312).

The most annoying thing is that they also seem to have disabled *U-Boot* access, even trying to brute force a keystroke during power up doesn't do anything. Nevertheless I think *U-Boot* is looking for something on the *SD-Card* as it initializes the *SD* slot when the camera is powered on with the reset button pressed:

```
Block:64KB Chip:8MB Name:"W25Q64FW"
SPI Nor total size: 8MB

EMMC/MMC/SD controller initialization.
MMC/SD Card:
    MID:         0x3
    Read Block:  512 Bytes
    Write Block: 512 Bytes
    Chip Size:   60906M Bytes (High Capacity)
    Name:        "SD64G"
    Chip Type:   SD
    Version:     2.0
    Speed:       25000000Hz
    Bus Width:   4bit
    Boot Addr:   0 Bytes
Interface:  MMC
  Device 0: Vendor: Man 035344 Snr e2cf5b82 Rev: 8.5 Prod: SD64G
            Type: Removable Hard Disk
            Capacity: 60906.0 MB = 59.4 GB (124735488 x 512)
Partition 1: Filesystem: FAT32 "NO NAME    "
```

I tried to copy the obvious, `uImage`, `update/uboot` etc... doesn't trigger anything.

I also tried to overflow the shell commands, messing with `/jffs0/etc/init.d/rcS`, nothing worked so far.

I'd be very happy with some fresh ideas I didn't try yet!

**Edit**

The flash serving as block device is a *W25Q64.W*, I dumped it using a brand new *CH341a* and a test clip, first time I did this, very cool. Now I have this dump but the `binwalk` analysis doesn't look promising:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
102060        0x18EAC         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
5767168       0x580000        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
6512540       0x635F9C        gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
6512780       0x63608C        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
6512968       0x636148        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6513460       0x636334        Zlib compressed data, compressed
6513640       0x6363E8        gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
[hundreds of lines of those]
8257536       0x7E0000        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
```

Here's the entropy graph
[image: binwalk entropy graph]
which seems to indicate a huge chunk of the firmware is either encrypted of compressed.

Comment: No way to pull a flash dump of the bootflash in some way? Boot log tells that there is some sort of SPI flash on the board. Post a pic of the board backside, too if possible

Comment: Yes that's exact;y what I ordered, will update the post if I get further, thanks!

Comment: Picture of reverse side of the PCB should be quick to do though since you only need to unscrew the 4 corner screws and then make the picture of whats at the back of the board. Knowing if there is useful stuff there helps massively

Comment: would be interested if this goes any further as I'm working on a xshcam doorbell running the same OS (Huawei liteOs 1.4.6). Block:64KB Chip:8MB Name:"W25Q64FW"
SPI Nor total size: 8MB
Camera OV9732 I can Uboot but doesn't help if there are proprietary blobs for the drivers for camera module and wifi etc..

Comment: Linux kernels are usually compressed and get uncompressed by a small stub. Possible to share the flashdump? Also: JFFS2 allows compressed files, too.

Comment: I've been digging deep on this board and its software: it turns out this is not an embedded Linux based OS but a complete light OS (hence the name) by Huawei. Very little to be done as the main partition is a do-it-all encrypted executable (sofia). It can run OpenIPC but the WiFi chipset is not supported. I am trying to find a presumably present USB port, following up here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/611725/what-is-this-port-4-holes-2x1-8v-pairs

Comment: @tvathome wait you can actually enter Uboot? I never could, even by shorting some pins on the flash.There are interesting parameters to try if you reach the Uboot prompt.